# Find the youngest customer grouped by province

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT a.province, c.birth_date, c.name 
FROM customer c
JOIN address a ON (c.cust_id = a.cust_id) 
GROUP BY a.province 
ORDER BY birth_date DESC;
```

I want to find the youngest customer in each province. The query above doesn't work.

Comment: Use `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Province ORDER BY birth_date DESC)` in CTE. If there is more than one youngest customer in some province does you need to select them all?

Comment: The question is not specific enough for there to be one right answer. If you just want the age and not the rest of the details then group by a.province as you have and use the `MAX(birth_date)` as your only `SELECT`ed column. If you need the full customer record and don't have a mysql version prior to 8.0 then a CTE similar to tgburgin's suggestion, using `ROW_NUMBER()` if you want at most one row per province or `[DENSE_]RANK()` if you want multiple rows if more than one person has the lowest age.

Comment: If you don't have 8.0 or 10.2, you must use a subquery.  See [_Groupwise-Max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

Answer (score 0):

```
with CustomerRank as (
    select
        a.province
        ,c.name
        ,dense_rank() over(partition by a.province order by c.birth_date desc) as AgeRank
    from customer c
    join address a on c.cust_id = a.cust_id
)
select *
from CustomerRank a
where a.AgeRank = 1;
```

Example fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=016888fbaf40093edfdf7ad22412c215

The idea is to create a list on which you can then pick the answer you need. In this case, generating a ranking of birth_date per province (AgeRank) then picking all the rows where AgeRank is 1 (i.e. the youngest as we've order by birth_date desc).